# How can i update Data extension using SQl in MC Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Hi i am trying to achieve

SELECT
    name,
    email(primary key)
FROM
    DeOne,
    DeTwo
Update
DeThird

Fields are same in all 3

Can Someone correct me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using UNIONS. Unions are a way to combine data of two or more dataextensions and insert the result into the dataextension (or table) of your choice.

Here are some nice posts regarding unions:

- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)
- [2](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/)

Depending on your use case you need to switch between union and union all. Union will perform in a way that you will only get distinct rows while union all will not. Because you have a primary key in your dataextension you might get into conflicts when you have an email adress in both source target dataextensions. Just wanted to inform you, that you are aware of it.

The Query would be:

```
SELECT name, email
FROM DEOne
UNION ALL
SELECT name, email
FROM DETwo
```

The Target is DEThird.

Maybe you need to add aliases (but i dont think so)

```
SELECT one.name, one.email
FROM DEOne as one
UNION ALL
SELECT two.name, two.email
FROM DETwo as two
```

Target is DEThird.

Comment: Thanks Johannes